# how to implement google's protocol buffers via http

Tags: go, network-programming, protocols, protocol-buffers, network-protocols

I am using **google's protocol buffers** to send data from client to server.

**Client and server both are written in Golang.**

I think it uses plain tcp to send data from `client` to `server`.

**Sample client code:**

```
func getFakeTransaction() *proto.Transaction {
    transaction := new(proto.Transaction)
    transaction.ClientId = "client_1"
    transaction.ClientName = "Europa"

    items := new(proto.Items)
    items.ItemId = 1
    items.ItemName = "Space suite"
    items.ItemValue = 2000
    transaction.Items = items

    return transaction
}

func readDataFromExternalDatasource() *proto.Transaction {
    return getFakeTransaction()
}

func sentDataToServer(data []byte) {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8080")
    defer conn.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error while dialing server: %s\n", err.Error())
        return
    }
    sentBytes, err := conn.Write(data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error sending bytes to serve: %s\n", err.Error())
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Sent %d bytes\n", sentBytes)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting client..")
    data := readDataFromExternalDatasource()
    dataInByteArr, err := protoc.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error while Marshal data: %s", err.Error())
    }
    for {
        sentDataToServer(dataInByteArr)
        time.Sleep(1000)
    }
}
```

**How to send data from client to server via `HTTP` using protocol buffers in Golang**?

Comment: Your code establishes a tcp connection (see the literal `"tcp"` in net.Dial). So what is the question?

Comment: "Protocol Buffers" is essentially the protocol--it even has protocol in the name :)

Comment: Can we use protocol buffer over http

Comment: Yes you can. But why?

Comment: My webserver has build in caching for http

Comment: Also could you please guide me how I can use protobuff with http using golang

Comment: I suggest you google "how does protobuf work?" and start from there.    There are worked examples here, https://github.com/golang/protobuf for instance

Comment: Thank you for the link @Vorsprung. I went to the above link but I didn't found any examples other than the the `Marshal` and `UnMarshal ` example in `README` but I found no example how `client` can send data to `server` using `http`

Comment: This link help me `https://jacobmartins.com/2016/05/24/practical-golang-using-protobuffs/`.

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **successfully implemented** protobuff vai http.

**Credits**: `https://jacobmartins.com/2016/05/24/practical-golang-using-protobuffs/`

**Sample_Client:**

```
func getFakeTransaction() *proto.Transaction {
    transaction := new(proto.Transaction)
    transaction.ClientId = "client_1"
    transaction.ClientName = "Europa"

    items := new(proto.Items)
    items.ItemId = 1
    items.ItemName = "Space suite"
    items.ItemValue = 2000
    transaction.Items = items

    return transaction
}

func sendMessage(transaction *proto.Transaction) {
    message, err := protoc.Marshal(transaction)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error while marshaling message: %s", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    _, err = http.Post("http://localhost:8080", "", bytes.NewBuffer(message))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error while post request to server: %s", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Sent %d bytes to server\n", len(message))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting client..")
    transaction := getFakeTransaction()
    for {
        sendMessage(transaction)
        // time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

**Sample Server:**

```
func printMessage(t *proto.Transaction) {
    clientId := t.GetClientId()
    clientName := t.GetClientName()
    items := t.GetItems()
    fmt.Printf("ClientId: %s, ClientName: %s, Items: %s\n", clientId, clientName, items)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Staring server..")
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        message, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error while reading data from client: ", err.Error())
            return
        }
        transaction := new(proto.Transaction)
        // protoc.Unmarshal(message, &transaction)
        if err = transaction.XXX_Unmarshal(message); err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error while unmarshaling client message: %s", err.Error())
            return
        }
        printMessage(transaction)
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}
```

**Sample Protofile:**

```
syntax="proto3";

package proto;

enum Status {
    SUCCESS = 0;
    INPROGRESS = 1;
    FAILED = 2;
}

message Items {
    int32 itemId = 1;
    string itemName = 2;
    int32 itemValue = 3;
    Status status = 4;
}

message Transaction {
    string clientId = 1;
    string clientName = 2;
    Items items = 3;
}
```